# MATLAB Bar graph + HeatMap/Imagesc

Tags: matlab, bar-chart, matlab-figure, heatmap

I would like to merge a bar graph with a heat map (specifically produced via image/imagesc fxn), such that the bars correspond to the rows of the map. Something like:

[image: http://www.pnas.org/content/107/15/6958/F3.large.jpg]

Is there a way to do this in matlab?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to generate a figure similar to the above using the `subplot` command along with `imagesc` and `barh`.  That solves the general problem of alignment, but the attractive figure you gave as an example also includes many other small modifications (custom colormap, custom code for horizontal error bars, possibly some re-ordering of the y-axis, y-axis re-labeling, changing the default plotting font, as well as some cropping of the whitespace between the adjacent figures.)

Comment: Thanks! Definitely helped with better google-searching (ie for small modifications).  Specifically, I was looking for:

http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2012/12/21/figure-margins-subplot-spacings-and-more/

Comment: +1, thanks for the relevant link, @Jac.